# get string value from list by regex

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have a two strings:

```
num = '#123'

line = '#123 random text generator #111 #222 #333'
```

I wish to get all the numbers of the format `'#xyz' if num == first number in line.`

I've used regex to get the first number `(#123)` by:

```
re.findall(r'[#]\d{3,10}', line)
```

and I try to test this condition by:

```
if re.findall(r'[#]\d{3,10}', line)[:1] == num:
```

I've tried to get the re.findall into a parameter and print its length and type, and it says it's length 0 and type list. It's confusing me because [:1] should give me the '#123' string that it finds right? It seems like the list is empty but I can't figure out why.

More specifically my code has `matrix = [['#123'] ['#234'] ['#345'] ['#666']]`.

```
def test(matrix,txt):
  for num_group in matrix:
    print num_group
    for num in num_group:
      for line in txt:
        if re.findall(r'[#]\d{3,10}', line)[:1] == num:
          print "found some more numbers in the line number!"
          print line
          more_nums = re.findall(r'[#]\d{3,10}', line)[1:]
          matrix[num_group].append(nums)
```

So my end result should append `#111 #222` and `#333` to the `matrix[0]` that contains `#123`.

Comment: You should probably add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: sry about that :)

Comment: Can you use the PyPi regex module? You can do it with one pattern then. Or are you limited to Python `re`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PyPi but I want to keep it as simple as possible so I guess no external modules are needed beyond what I've done. It should work also with my code..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew don't understand what you're trying to make different with that code...?

Comment: Please clarify what your algorithm is to get  your expected output.

Comment: matrix = [ [#123,#111,#222,#333] [#234] [#345] [#666] ]

Comment: What is `num`? Is it a string? Right now it looks like a comment.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you're right it wasn't clear enough. it's a string. I've updated the post.

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky. Please fix the quotes carefully throughout your question. Specifically the matrix. Python uses suck typing, but that does not mean that you can post code that doesn't run and expect us to understand it.

Comment: Also, what version of Python is this? I feel like that might be important for the answer.

Comment: Also, could you explain why you use `[:1]` instead of `[0]` please? Seems like overkill, and harder to understand...

Comment: @MadPhysicist I actually tried [0] and for some reason it says that my 'index is out of range'. I think it's something to do with an empty list but I couldn't understand how.

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky. It sure does. You should check `if ...:` to make sure the result is non-empty and non-`None` before you use it. That actually ties in nicely with not rerunning the regex twice to begin with.

Comment: What are the actual inputs to your function? Does `txt` contain empty lines?

Comment: The issue that you *did* describe completely looks like this: https://ideone.com/TPqcjZ. On the other hand, the piece of code you show in the second part can not be run because you don't show any inputs.

Comment: @MadPhysicist txt doesn't contain any empty lines. If I add the != 0 and != 'None' conditions to the if, it still doesn't work.
With the string and num inputs in my post it should run right?

Comment: When you've posted a reproducible example that shows the unexpected behavior, I'll be glad to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check via python string inbuilt method 'startswith' and then you can use some logic there , Here is my approach :

```
import re
pattern=r'#\d+'
num = '#123'

line = '#123 random text generator #111 #222 #333'

matrix = [['#123'],['#234'],['#345'],['#666']]

if line.startswith(num):
    match=re.findall(pattern,line)
    for index,value in enumerate(matrix):
        if match[0] in value:
            value.extend(match[1:])

print(matrix)
```

output:

```
[['#123', '#111', '#222', '#333'], ['#234'], ['#345'], ['#666']]
```

Edit :

As you said you want limit the search for only num then you can add little logic before above code , Here is updated code:

```
import re
pattern=r'#\d+'
num = '#123'

line = '#123 random text generator #111 #222 #333'

matrix = [['#123'],['#234'],['#345'],['#666']]
if len(line.split()[0])==len(num):
    if line.startswith(num):
        match=re.findall(pattern,line)
        for index,value in enumerate(matrix):
            if match[0] in value:
                value.extend(match[1:])

print(matrix)
```

Test case 1:

```
line = '#1234 random text generator #111 #222 #333' #not exact string
```

output:

```
[['#123'], ['#234'], ['#345'], ['#666']] #no effect
```

Test case 2:

```
line = '#1234 random text generator #111 #222 #333' #exact string
```

output:

```
[['#123', '#111', '#222', '#333'], ['#234'], ['#345'], ['#666']]
```

Comment: This seems to work better! I'm still having a logical problem when the line startswith '#123' but it's for example '#1231 random text generator #111 #222 #333'.
Is there a way to get 'exactly' the value of num?

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky its confusing , can you explain what exactly you are looking ?

Comment: Your example seems to find the text line in the txt file, but it also finds any line that starts with the same but not exact match. For example lines that start with #1234 will also match the startswith('#123'). Is there a way to limit it somehow to find only the num value?

Comment: @YafimSimanovsky i have updated the answer, if my solution helped you, Then you can accept the answer.